# regex to fail when word surrounded by spaces is matched

Tags: regex

I have the current Regex

```
/^[A-Za-z-' ]+$/
```

I would like to maintain the above but fail/exclude when there is the word ' hello ' in the string surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution here would be to just add a negative lookahead assertion at the start of the pattern which rules out `hello` as a standalone word:

```
/^(?!.*\bhello\b)[A-Za-z' -]+$/
```

Note also that I have moved the `-` dash to the *end* of your character class.  You current regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z-' ]+$/
```

actually says to take all characters in the range from `z` to `'`, which is probably not what you intend here.

For a case insensitive version, you could use the `/i` flag:

```
/^(?!.*\bhello\b)[A-Z' -]+$/i
```

Note that the character class now doesn't have to list out lowercase letters, since they will be included already.

Comment: ++ for little detail. Although it's not actually going to interpret as *`z` to `'`* because there's another range `a-z` in front of it. But for avoiding ambiguity, always escape the dash `\-` or put it at the end.

Comment: also how to make this word match case insensitive?

Comment: Is there also a way to match start of string or end of string instead of one of the spaces? Eg 'hello sir' or 'sir hello'. basically I want to match the word hello, but not as part of a word